# Maths olympiad question with subset of a $55$ elements of which $2$ numbers differ by 9.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that every subset of $55$ elements of the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,98,99,100\}$ contains at least $2$ numbers with a difference of $9$.

What I've done is used the following trick:

Divide the set into $\{1,\ldots,50\}$ and the second set is determined by the last element of the first set (i.e. $50$) $+$ the elements of the first set consecutively. Then there are $50$ pairs that differ from $50$. So by the pigeon hole principle if you select 55 elements there are 2 elements who form a pair with a difference of $9$.

> Would this proof considered to be valid?

Comment: @Arthur I meant the $2^{nd}$  part of your question . I'll edit that

Comment: I don't understand your argument.  I'd work with pairs of the form $(1,10),\cdots,(9,18),(19,28),\cdots, (27,36),(37,46),\cdots$.

Comment: See my explanation in answer beneath.

Comment: Use the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: I already said that in my OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide $S=\{1,2,\ldots,100\}$ into the following sets:
$$
\{1,10,19,28,37,46,55,64,73,82,91,100\},\quad\text{12 elements} \\
\{2,11,20,29,38,47,56,65,74,83,92\}, \quad\text{11 elements}\\
\{3,12,21,30,39,48,57,66,75,84,93\}, \quad\text{11 elements}\\
\{4,13,22,31,40,49,58,67,76,85,94\},\quad\text{11 elements} \\
\{5,14,23,32,41,50,59,68,77,86,95\}, \quad\text{11 elements}\\
\{6,15,24,33,42,51,60,69,78,87,96\}, \quad\text{11 elements}\\
\{7,16,25,34,43,52,61,70,79,88,97\},\quad\text{11 elements} \\
\{8,17,26,35,44,53,62,71,80,89,98\}, \quad\text{11 elements}\\
\{9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90,99\}\quad\text{11 elements}.
$$
If we pick 55 elements out of these 9 subsets, then in at least one of these subsets, we will have picked at least 7 elements. In such case, in that subset, among the 7 elements, there will be at least a pair of consecutive elements, i.e. of difference 9.

Answer (score 0):

How does the fact that we have $50$ pairs with a difference $50$ helps you conclude there is a pair of integers with differnece $9$?

Here's a hint how to solve this problem. Try to construct a counterexample. Divide the set into subsets modulo $9$. So for example one of the subsets would be: $\{1,10,19,28,37,46,55,64,73,82,91,100\}$. What's the biggest number of integers you can include without having a pair of integers with a difference $9$? Now do the same for all subsets.

Comment: With the above question I meant that if you have a series of 2n consecutive integers (say $a + 1, a+2,  \ldots , a+ 2n-1, a + 2n$) than there are n pairs who have a difference of $n$ namely $(a+1, a + n+1), (a+2, a+ n+2),\ldots , (a + n, a + 2n)$ Now one can state by the pigeon hole principle if one selects more than n elements there are two pairs liable to differ n from eachother.

Comment: @AnonymousI I still don't see how this will help you with the question

Comment: I made a wrong assumption.